# Large field values are not visible in Kibana dashboard

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to display **ErrorDetails** field information over Kibana dashboards. My data seems indexed since it is available under discover tab, but when I try to use same field in Visualization or it doesn't give any result over there.

Results on Discover tab :

```
@timestamp
Mar 17, 2021 @ 17:45:46.857
    
ErrorDetails
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:126)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.common.emxNavigatorErrorPage_jsp._jspService(emxNavigatorErrorPage_jsp.java:237)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    
ErrorType
SEVERE

Time
Feb 22, 2021 9:04:35 PM
    
_id
uRkdQHgB5IxHfqi3CEya
    
_index
localhost_logs
```

I tried to update the ignore_above setting also for same index and field, but that also is not working.
I understand this is weird to display whole error message but I don't have any pattern to filter it more and want to display complete information in one data table column. Any suggestion please.